# The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. You will need to power off or reset the virtual machine at this point

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, vmware

I have recently downloaded ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32 bit) iso image and trying to install it under VMWare Workstation 9.0. which is under Windows 7 (64 bit). when i start installation it says:

> The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. You will need
>   to power off or reset the virtual machine at this point.

Does anyone here help me out to install this?

Comment: Same error here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with kernel and VMWare version you are using. My one liner : Upadate VMware version to make it work perfectly. For a detailed view though, Its a known issue, see [here](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1010141).

Comment: I have updated to VMWare Workstation 10 and same error while installing the 12.04 version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thats real strange coz It worked perfectly fine for another user facing same problem as you. ?? Read here. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312295/installation-of-ubuntu-12-04-in-vmware)

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
vmware-modconfig --console -install-all
```

It'll recompile vmware kernel modules.

Also, Enable virtualization from BIOS.

Comment: virtualization is enabled in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the latest version of both:

Vmware and Ubuntu.

Vmware Workstation latest version is number 10 and it has a free version if you can´t afford to pay Vmware workstation:

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0

Ubuntu is always free and the latest stable version is 13.10:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

I would use the 32 bit version to virtualize as it will take less resources.

It is also very easy to install on virtualbox and runs as well very nicely and it is also a free alternative, hope you get your problem fixed.